# Re-assign exception from within a python __exit__ block

Tags: python, exception, with-statement

From within an `__exit__` block in a custom cursor class I want to catch an exception so I can in turn throw a more specific exception. What is the proper way to do this?

```
class Cursor:
    def __enter__(self):
        ...

    def __exit__(self, ex_type, ex_val, tb):
        if ex_type == VagueThirdPartyError:
            # get new more specific error based on error code in ex_val and
            # return that one in its place.
            return False # ?
        else:
            return False
```

Raising the specific exception within the `__exit__` block seems like a hack, but maybe I'm over thinking it.

Comment: Why does it seem like a hack to just raise the exception?

Comment: I thought there might have been another way to do it since the context manager catches any exceptions within the main block, stores it, and then passes it through to __exit__ to approve or veto. Raising within __exit__ seemed like it would be more of an expansion of its responsibilities based on its arguments - but I was clearly over thinking it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The proper procedure is to raise the new exception inside of the `__exit__` handler.

You should *not* raise the exception that was passed in though; to allow for context manager chaining, in that case you should just return a falsey value from the handler. Raising your own exceptions is however perfectly fine.

Note that it is better to use the identity test `is` to verify the type of the passed-in exception:

```
def __exit__(self, ex_type, ex_val, tb):
    if ex_type is VagueThirdPartyError:
        if ex_val.args[0] == 'foobar':
            raise SpecificException('Foobarred!')

        # Not raising a new exception, but surpressing the current one:
        if ex_val.args[0] == 'eggs-and-ham':
            # ignore this exception
            return True

        if ex_val.args[0] == 'baz':
            # re-raise this exception
            return False

    # No else required, the function exits and `None` is  returned
```

You could also use `issubclass(ex_type, VagueThirdPartyError)` to allow for subclasses of the specific exception.

Comment: Or possibly:  `if issubclass(ex_type,VagueThirdPartyError)`

Comment: **tl;dr** for Googlers: custom `__exit__` not propagating exceptions? Don't return anything/return a falsey value.