# python context manager not passing exceptions

Tags: python, exception, contextmanager

Why does the following unit test fail, and how do I get my context manager to pass exceptions properly? I'm using python 3.

test.py:

```
class test(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return args
```

test_test.py:

```
import test
import unittest

class TestTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_test(self):

        with self.assertRaises(OverflowError):
            with test.test():
                raise OverflowError()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running the unit test, I get an error complaining that OverflowError was not raised. Why does this happen, and what do I need to do so that my context manager properly propagates exceptions?

Comment: Why are you doing `return args` at all? What did you think that was supposed to do?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, somehow I had convinced myself that a previous version of my context manager was eating the values of `return` statements within the context body. Also somehow, adding that `return` broke my code in a way that at the time gave the correct behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
def __exit__(self, ex_type, ex_val, tb):
    return ex_type, ex_val, tb
```

The return value of `__exit__` implies that you want to suppress those errors raised inside the context block.

Simply change it to return nothing or raise the error if any overflow error occurs. If any truthy value is returned, the context block suppresses the error. You need to return false. An example is as follows:

```
def __exit__(self, ex_type, ex_val, tb):
    if ex_type is OverflowError:
        return False
    return True
```

**Edit** Martijn Pieters as always has a better [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344080/4131059) than me.