# Exception from With statement is not passed to custom context manager __exit__

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, contextmanager

I am experimenting with With statement and custom context managers. I do not understand why  an exception raised when executing the With statement is not passed to my custom context manager `__exit__()`?

The class with custom context managers is as follows:

```
class with_point():

    def __init__(self, numer, denom):
        self.numer = numer
        self.denom = denom
    
    def __enter__(self):
        print("This is entry point")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("An error of type {} with value {} happened".format(exc_type,exc_value))
        if exc_type is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The class is supposed to accept two numeric values, later used as numerator and denominator of a fraction.

Next I run code that uses With Statement to create an object of `with_point` type and calculate the fraction:

```
from with_class import with_point
with with_point(8,0) as wp:
    try:
        fr = wp.numer / wp.denom
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When I run the latter code the output looks like:

> This is entry point
> division by zero
> An error of type None with value None happened

This is contrary from what I expect because the language reference [indicates](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

> The context manager’s `__exit__()` method is invoked. If an exception
> caused the suite to be exited, its type, value, and traceback are
> passed as arguments to `__exit__()`. Otherwise, three None arguments are
> supplied.

I expect that as per documentation the **division by zero** exception is to be passed to the `__exit__` context manager. However, this does not happen, and the context manager receives **None**.

I did a bit of a search for similar question here, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839828/python-context-manager-not-passing-exceptions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344002/re-assign-exception-from-within-a-python-exit-block/15344080#15344080). First link does not help because it suggests to return False from the `__exit__` if an exception is raised within With statement, and this is exactly what I do.  Second link suggests to raise a new exception in the `__exit__` handler, probably a fair idea, but it says nothing about why 'None' exception is passed from With statement to the context manager instead of `divide by zero' exception.

What do I need to change in (1) custom context manager (2) With statement (3) maybe both to have DivideByZero exception passed from With statement to `__exit__` handler?

Comment: what if you remove the `try/except` in the `with` block?

Comment: Do not use try/except, just run `fr = wp.numer / wp.denom` within the context manager.

Comment: If I don't use try/except, an error ( An error of type <class 'ZeroDivisionError'> with value division by zero happened) is thrown, and `__exit__` handler is not invoked

Comment: Actually, the ` An error of type <class 'ZeroDivisionError'> with value division by zero happened)` message was from the `__exit__` handler, just didn't recognize it at first :) Thank you guys for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the document said :

> If an exception **caused the suite to be exited**, its type, value, and
> traceback are passed as arguments to `__exit__()`. Otherwise, three None
> arguments are supplied.

In your case that "division by zero" exception didn't cause the suit to be exited because you except that in `except Exception as e:` part ! so it's silenced. If you remove the try/except, you will see that it passed to the `__exit__` because it is now unhandled inside the with statement, and it causes the suit to be exited.

To silence the exception inside `__exit__` docs says :

> If an exception is supplied, and the method wishes to suppress the
> exception (i.e., prevent it from being propagated), it should return a
> **"true"** value. Otherwise, the exception will be processed normally upon
> exit from this method.

Best way to do it is:

```
class with_point:

    def __init__(self, numer, denom):
        self.numer = numer
        self.denom = denom

    def __enter__(self):
        print("This is entry point")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("An error of type '{}' with value '{}' happened".format(exc_type, exc_value))
        return isinstance(exc_value, ZeroDivisionError)


with with_point(8, 0) as wp:
    fr = wp.numer / wp.denom
```

This is how you normally deal with context-manager. If the exception is `ZeroDivisionError` it will silenced, otherwise it propagates. try :

```
with with_point(8, '0') as wp:
    fr = wp.numer / wp.denom
```

Comment: If I remove Try/Except from With statement the output is:

This is entry point

An error of type <class 'ZeroDivisionError'> with value division by zero happened
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "with_call.py", line 6, in <module>

    fr = wp.numer / wp.denom

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

The ZeroDivisionError is thrown, and `__exit__' handler is not invoked

Comment: @vtm11 I'll update the answer to show how you can silence it

Comment: The first change you suggest (replace `return` statement in `__exit__` with ```return isinstance(exc_value, ZeroDivisionError)``` ) definitely works. Moreover, my initial setup worked fine too, I just didn't recognize a message from the `__exit__` handler in the output. My bad :) Thank you!

Comment: @vtm11 Emmm, you checked if `exc_type is None`, that means there is no exception to propagate, so returning True is unnecessary IMO.

Comment: Sure, I agree 100%, this is just to mention that the `__exit__' handler is invoked before the rest of output with traceback is printed too