# PyTest: Exclude modules / plugin line numbers in the assertion error

Tags: python

I remember reading some place that it was possible to stop Python from reporting line numbers in the called method / plugin code.

Currently I would get something like

```
tests/test.py:2: in test_xyz
    abc
someplace/shared.py:2: in abc
    raise AssertionError('ERROR)
E   AssertionError: 'ERROR'
```

What I would like is something like (exclude reference to shared.py)

```
tests/test.py:2: in test_xyz
    abc
E   AssertionError: 'ERROR'
```

Comment: How is this output being produced.  Are you printing these explicitly in a catch block, or is this happening by the exception not being caught and so being displayed by Python itself?

Comment: I am not catching the exception, so it is displayed by python its self.  I remember reading some place that there was something you could add to the top of the file containing the called method that would exclude it from the stack trace

Comment: I don't know of anything, but it could certainly exist.  My guess is that you're talking about the shebang line at the top of the file that actually causes python to be used to interpret that particular file.  It's also possible there's something that can be done at runtime by your code to affect how the python environment prints exceptions.  Unfortunately, I don't know of these mechanisms.  If anything, I would think this would be a parameter that python accepts when it is launched.  I'd suggest looking over the documentation for running python at the command line.

Comment: Another possibility maybe is to put a try/except around your entire code so that Python never prints any exception itself.  Then you'd have complete control over how to the exception was printed.  I know there is some control over this printing in the **traceback** python module.  If you could take this general approach, and if nothing in **traceback** would do quite what you want, you could always "print" the exception to a string, and then modify that string before actually printing it on stdout/stderr.

Comment: Wondering if this might be helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344002/re-assign-exception-from-within-a-python-exit-block - this addresses a different problem, but suggests that you could catch an exception globally and then be able to modify the default behavior.

Comment: I found it.   If you add the following then it will not report that file in the exception error
```
__tracebackhide__ = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the file will disable the file being reported in the stack trace, you can set it back to False to re-enable

```
__tracebackhide__ = True
```

Comment: Woo hoo!  Good to know.